# Count columns from sacct output with awk in bash

Tags: bash, awk, slurm

I work on a slurm cluster and I want to find how much cpu and memory I am currently using. My main problem is distinguishing between 8G and 8Gc for memory usage. (the former is the raw required memory, the later is the memory per core, hence I need to multiply it by the number of cores).

My approach thus far is:

```
function get_cpu_mem_count(){
    
 sum=0
 sacct --starttime=midnight --format=state,ncpus,ReqMem $1 | grep RUNNING | awk '{ sum += $2} END {print "num_of_cpus:\t", sum / 3 }'
 sum=0
 sacct --starttime=midnight --format=state,ncpus,ReqMem $1 | grep RUNNING | awk '{
            print "$(substr($4, 2, length($4)-1))"
            if ("$(substr($4, 2, length($4)-1))" -eq "c")
            {
                    if ($1 != 'extern' &&  $1 != 'batch')
                    {
                            print $4, ",\t", substr($4, 2, length($4)-2), ",\t", substr($4, 1, length($4)-2)
                            sum+=$2 * substr($4, 1, length($4)-2);
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                    print "adasda\t", $4, ",\t", substr($4, 2, length($4)-1), ",\t", substr($3, 1, length($4)-1)
                    sum+=$4;
            }
            fi
    } END {print "total_memory:\t", sum }'
```

}

The output of the initial command:

```
sacct --starttime=midnight --format=state,ncpus,ReqMem
```

looks like this:

```
ent_N=3_L+    RUNNING          8         8G 
     batch    RUNNING          8            
    extern    RUNNING          8            
ent_N=3_L+    RUNNING          8         8G 
     batch    RUNNING          8            
    extern    RUNNING          8            
ent_N=3_L+    RUNNING          8         8G 
     batch    RUNNING          8            
    extern    RUNNING          8
```

and so on. Each job has 3 outputs (batch script, actual job and some additional script for slurm (I think) ), which is why I divide the counted cpus by 3. My problem is that the first if statement is not working (it enters the scope even if there is no job with `Gc` set for memory. My approach might be very stupid (I am still learning bash/slurm), but I hope you understand my general idea and problem.

Thanks for any help and comments!

Comment: Did you consider `sacct --json` and using a json parser?

Comment: Not really, I don't know how this works. But I'll check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for `ReqTRES`, or maybe `AllocTRES`.

Here's an example inspired from `salloc` [page](https://slurm.schedmd.com/salloc.html) for a cluster that has hyper-threading turned on; you'll see that `ReqTRES` and `AllocTRES` return sightly different results:

```bash
$ salloc -n 3 --mem-per-cpu=100
salloc: Granted job allocation 17199
$ sacct -nPX -j "$SLURM_JOB_ID" -o jobid,reqtres,alloctres
17199|billing=3,cpu=3,mem=300M,node=1|billing=4,cpu=4,mem=400M,node=1
```

<sup>**note:** `-P` is for getting a parsable output, and `-X` is for ignoring the job steps, so that you get only one line per job ID</sup>

With that, you don't need to do any calculations, just take the `mem` value of `ReqTRES` or `AllocTRES`, depending on what you want to know:

```bash
sacct -nPX --starttime=midnight --format=reqtres |
awk -F ',' '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if (sub(/^mem=/,"",$i)) print $i }'
```

Comment: Took me a while, but now I understand what this does. It works perfectly fine, thank you!